# issue with Inserting SECTION in document with openoffice JAVA API

Tags: java

I am working on openoffice JAVA API to insert SECTION. I am following the following link:

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=519189#519189

I have a problem while executing the code in above link. I am not able to resolve the object "serviceFactory" (as follows), can anyone please tell me what type of this object is and how to get it??

```
xChildNamed = (XNamed) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
XNamed.class,
serviceFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextSection", document1));
```

Also, please elaborate what the following call does?

```
componentExport(document2, storeProps, tempDoc);
```

or, 
can someone please point me to a better solution.

Comment: I have figured out the issue. "serviceFactory" is obtained as follow:

    serviceFactory = (XMultiServiceFactory) UnoRuntime.queryInterface( MultiServiceFactory.class, xTextDocument );

and the following code is not needed

componentExport(document2, storeProps, tempDoc);

-Ali